# Unable to access certain properties of the ZF2 request object

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm testing `ZF2` beta4 at the moment, and I'm having some issues accessing some of the request properties from my controller.

From inside the `indexAction()`, here is an extract of what I get for the request object

`var_dump($this->request);` gives me:

```
object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request)#119 (14) {

  ["baseUrl":protected]=>
    string(0) ""

  [...]

  ["version":protected]=>
    string(3) "1.1"

  ["queryParams":protected]=>
    object(Zend\Stdlib\Parameters)#122 (1) {
      ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
      array(3) {
        ["q"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["param1"]=>
        string(6) "value1"
        ["param2"]=>
        string(6) "value2"
      }
    }
```

I can access some of the properties:
`var_dump($this->request->getBaseUrl());`  -> `string(0) ""`
`var_dump($this->request->getVersion());`  -> `string(3) "1.1"`

But I am having issues with others, for instance `$this->request->getQueryParams()` returns:

> Call to undefined method
>   Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request::getQueryParams()

From there I have a few questions:
**-Am I doing something wrong?**
If not:
**-How can I access the `queryParams` property?**
**-Is it common practice not to have methods to access certain properties (if so what's the point of having these properties if I can't access them) ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the properties you dumped are protected, it's why you needed a getter to fetch their values.

Existing getter for some properties don't mean that they exist for all :)

If you take a look at the source of `Zend\Http\Request` (which is inherited by `Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request`) you can see that the method name used to access the query param is [`query()`](https://github.com/Maks3w/zf2/blob/release-2.0.0beta4/library/Zend/Http/Request.php#L266)

*Note*: I agree that's a bit inconsistent.

**Warning**: It has been changed since the beta5 and it is now `getQuery()`

Protected and private members are used to ensure that the data won't be accessed directly.

It is mostly used for internal use only, or provided with a public setter/getter to allow transformation, error checking, etc.

For example, you may want to add type hinting.

```
class Car {

    public $engine;
}

$car = new Car();
$car->engine = new Truck();

// Having a public member doesn't allow me to check for valid type (I don't want a `Truck` to be set in place of an `Engine`)

class Car {
    private $engine;

    public setEngine(Engine $engine)
    {
        $this->engine = $engine;
        // Add additional code here
        $this->engine->warmUp();
    }
}

// Here I use type hinting to ensure validity of data, I also warmUp the Engine just after setting it.
```

Comment: `a bit inconsistent` ? IMO it's either consistent or it isn't. I love `Zend Framework` but it's a shame we still have those little discrepancies that impact your productivity.

Comment: well it's a bit inconsistent because it is not prefixed with `get` and there are no reason for that (that's why they corrected it)

Comment: Precisely my point. I hope they will do a complete review of the code for the release candidate so we can start with a good clean and consistent code (if you follow the logic it should even be called `getQueryParams`, not `getQuery`).

Answer (score -2):

- no
- getQuery()
- for internal use

Comment: getQuery() is not available in beta4